# Object arraylist error

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to generate random food and detergent objects and add them to a products arraylist,(food and detergent classes extend products),but when I try to read from the arraylist all the random properties I inserted are 0 or null. I can provide you with the code for the other classes if needed but I don't think that there is a problem with the constructors. Thanks beforehand.

```
    ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String a = sb.toString();

        Random generator = new Random();
        int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(manufacturers.length);
        String b = manufacturers[randomIndex];

        int randomIndex2 = generator.nextInt(suppliers.length);
        String c = suppliers[randomIndex2];

        Random r = new Random();
        int d = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(7, 28 + 1);
        int e = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(12, 31 + 1);
        int f = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-1, 30 + 1);
        int g = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-8, 25 + 1);

        products.add(new Food(a, b, c, d, e, f, g));
```

here is the food constructor:

`Food(String name,String manufacturer,String supplier,int purchase_price,int selling_price,int sale_date,int expiration_date){
        super(name,manufacturer,supplier,purchase_price,selling_price,sale_date);
        expiration_date=this.expiration_date;
}`

and the products superclass code:

```
    Products(String name,String manufacturer,String supplier,int purchase_price,int selling_price,int sale_date){ 
    name=this.name;
    manufacturer=this.manufacturer;
    supplier=this.supplier;
    purchase_price=this.purchase_price;
    selling_price=this.selling_price;
    sale_date=this.sale_date;}`
```

Comment: Could you try and isolate the problem in a smaller section of code?

Comment: Just edited the code. The edited question contains only the part for the food class objects. I later use the same code to add objects from the detergent class to the products arraylist.

Comment: Reading the code, why do you create 3 instances of `Random`? You don't have to create a new one every time you need it, create it once and use it throughout the rest of your code. Now I'm going to try and see why your `products.add` isn't working. Since that is where the problem is, right?

Comment: Could you add the code for `Food` constructor as well?

Comment: I thought there might be a problem with the random instances so I created new instances. Yeah the problem occurs when I try to insert the objects to the arraylist. When I print the properties before the appending gives the expected values. I can provide you with the food constructor code.

Comment: Oh, well, the `Random` instance(s) are not the problem and since you can output the correct values before adding them to your `products` list we should have a look at the `Food` constructor as mentioned before. :)

Comment: ... now we need to see the constructor for the superclass. On another note, you need not create a character array to select random alphabetical characters. You can simply use ASCII arithmetic like so: `char c = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + (int) 'a');`

Comment: Hm, your constructor seems fine if it says `public Food(String etc.)` and not just `Food(String etc.)` but I assume that's the case. Just a thought: try and change your `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Food> foods` as it might be that the `ArrayList` you are currently using only accepts `Products` Objects.

Comment: variables called "a", "b", ... really? nowadays there is no need to not spend some bytes and use meaningful names like "product", "manufacturer", "supplier" - sure that code is small, but probably will get longer... Do not think the problem is not somewhere - test it! - like creating a Food with constants `new Food("food", "manufacturer", "supplier",...)` and then do what ever you do to test what is in it.

Comment: @steven Maybe the issue is in the parent constructor. For example, that constructor might accidentally do something like `name = name;` instead of `this.name = name;`.

Comment: @synchronizer you probably meant `c = random.nextInt(26) + 'a';` - no need for the `chars` array; or even `c = 'a' + random.nextInt('z'-'a'+1);`

Comment: @synchronizer I don't think he wrote his own "superclass" so the `super()` will call the constructor of `Object` and that should not give any problems.

Comment: @steven Now see. :)

Comment: since the problem is saving the data we need to see how it is saved and retrieved

Comment: `name=this.name;` should be `this.name=name;` I think, Isn't it?

Comment: @Blasanka isn't it the same?

Comment: @Blasanka - SURE

Comment: @Far  `a = b` means that the value of `b` is assigned to `a`, that is, `a` is set with the value of  `b`, `b` is unchanged

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Actually both of your examples require a cast, i.e. `(char)(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be in the `Products` constructor:

```
Products(String name,String manufacturer,String supplier,int purchase_price,int selling_price,int sale_date) { 
    name=this.name;
    manufacturer=this.manufacturer;
    supplier=this.supplier;
    purchase_price=this.purchase_price;
    selling_price=this.selling_price;
    sale_date=this.sale_date;
}
```

The left-hand-side of the constructor statements above should assign the `this` pointer to the argument passed to the constructor parameter list, not the other way around. Your constructor sets the local parameter list arguments to whatever `this`.respectiveProperty is before any properties have been set (`null` or `0`). In other words, your constructor is a no-op since the constructor arguments are temporaries that disappear after we have left the constructor scope.

What you meant to do:

```
Products(String name,String manufacturer,String supplier,int purchase_price,int selling_price,int sale_date) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.purchase_price = purchase_price;
    this.selling_price = selling_price;
    this.sale_date = sale_date;
}
```

Comment: @Far No problem. The lesson here is not to be so quick to dismiss the possibility that something is the source of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some usage of `this` keyword that I took from the [JavaTPoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword)

1. `this` can be used to refer current class instance variable.
2. `this` can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
3. `this()` can be used to invoke current class constructor.
4. `this` can be passed as an argument in the method call.
5. `this` can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
6. `this` can be used to return the current class instance from the
   method.

In your `Food` constructor

```
expiration_date=this.expiration_date;
```

should be

```
this.expiration_date= expiration_date;
```

And in the `Products` constructor all the assignment should be

```
this.name = name;
this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
this.supplier = supplier;
this.purchase_price = purchase_price;
this.selling_price = selling_price;
this.sale_date = sale_date;
```

You know that `this.name` refer to member variable of `Products` class(inherited). What happen here is `name = this.name;` you are assign member variable value to parameter value. Out of the scope of constructor it is dissapear. Values that coming from the object never save to member variables.